# if else condition in Ajax and Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new in Ajax and JQuery and the simple requirement is to display a value as selected by the user using the `number` input field.

My code is as below:

```
<input type="text" id="number" />
<span id="display"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#number').keyup(function (){
        if($('#number').text($(this).val())===1){
            $("#display").html("15,000");
        }
        else if('#number').text($(this).val())==2){
            $("#display").html("28,000");
        }
        else if('#number').text($(this).val())==3){
            $("#display").html("39,000");
        }
        else if('#number').text($(this).val())==4){
           $("#display").html("48,000");
        }
        else if('#number').text($(this).val())==5){
           $("#display").html("55,000");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to show the expected and received text for your application, and what you tried to fix this.

Comment: Yes, my exact requirement is when user type 1 as input in input type field the 15000 is display inside <span id="display"></span>. Similarly 2,3,4,5 used

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the clarification. Minor note: please edit additional information that is fundamental to answering the question into the question itself instead of posting it as a comment. I've now upvoted it so it should be pretty clear to other users, no direct need to edit this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Ajax. Your syntax is not valid.

First of all, you have many statements with ommited bracket such as this statement:

```
else if('#number').text($(this).val())==2)
```

By adding a bracket in front of `('#number')` the code is fixed.

But the condition of the `if` statement is not what we need. Such a statement checks if [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method returned `true`. This method sets the text contents of the matched elements. Obviously, you do not need to use it. All you need to do is check the value of the input. This can be done with the help of the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

So, your code should look like:

```
$(function() {     
    $('#number').keyup(function (){
        if($(this).val() == 1){
            $("#display").html("15,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 2){
            $("#display").html("28,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 3){
            $("#display").html("39,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 4){
            $("#display").html("48,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 5){
            $("#display").html("55,000");
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82t86kqw/1/

As already mentioned in comments, such type of construction is usually performed using `switch` / `case` statements. Having to much `if` / `else`   isn`t best practice.

Comment: "Your syntax isn't valid" doesn't explain *why* it isn't valid.

Comment: Probably it's better to use `switch` and `case`. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes,  I`ve updated my answer. Thanks for the remark

Comment: @ Mosh Feu, yes you are right. But didn`t wan to make too much changes  in initial code.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr You can use backticks (\`) to indicate code fragments in the text. Not making too much changes is OK, but you could use a sentence like "but usually this is performed using switch / case statements". "This has nothing to do with Ajax" should be a comment below the question, not part of the answer. Using more sections in your answer makes it look more professional. Just a few hints for creating better answers. Upvoted.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Thanks for the remarks one more time! :)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response